Name of TV show for kids featuring a man in a workshop and his dog
I remember few details, TV show for kids probably educative featuring an old man and his dog, I think they were in the old man's workshop. If i recall correctly the dog was one of those hairy dogs like the one in the picture. 
The only episode I remember they were working with nails and they drop them, so the man takes a magnet and put it inside a jar in a way he could lift the nails and release them from the magnet easily.
I watched this in the 80s and the origin of the show is probably European or American.


Was the dog real or a puppet?
Latter case, I immediately had to think of The Fraggles, similar to the Muppets, but from the UK. Go to the page and scroll down a bit to see the old Doc Crystal (an inventor) and his dog Sprocket.
I'm not 100% sure on that since it's been soo long (only seen it a few times in the 80's) and I don't really remember any real educational elements, although I might have been too young to really notice them.

Just a footnote: the show was called Fraggle Rock the main version of which was filmed in Toronto, and was Canadian, not American or British. In this version Gerry Parkes played Doc (as an inventor). The Fraggle Rock segments remained the same through all versions, but the Doc'n'Sprocket segments were localized, similarly to how Sesame Street was handled. In the UK version, The Captain (Fulton Mackay) was a Scottish lighthouse keeper; in Germany, Doc (Hans-Helmut Dickow) was once again Doc and an inventor, and in France, Doc (Michel Robin) was a chef, but Sprocket was called Croquette.

It sounds like you are describing Doc and Einstein in Back to the Future, but that was a trilogy of movies.
